# How to get intellisense in a module where the class is not defined, only passed to?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, es6-class

**TL;DR**: Is there a way to enable intellisense for types/variables passed between modules in vscode?

In this scenario, I have 3 modules/files:

---

Test.js

```
// Test.js
export default class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.whatever = {
      a: "a",
      b: "b"
    };
  }

  someFunc() {
    console.log(this.whatever.b);
  }
}
```

OtherTest.js

```
// OtherTest.js
export default arg => {
  arg.someFunc();
};
```

index.js

```
//index.js
import Test from "./Test";
import OtherTest from "./OtherTest";
const test = new Test();
OtherTest(test);
```

---

Running the code in index.js, the console prints 'b', as expected.

Using vscode, how could the editor be made "aware" of what kind of variable was passed to the function in OtherTest.js, so I can have all members of the Test class popup in the intellisense?

I suppose it would be something done in vscode, since typed arguments are out of question, but I have no idea aside from TypeScript, which is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_examples):

> By default the JavaScript language service will analyze and provide IntelliSense for all files in your JavaScript project.

However, you can specify files you want to include or exclude in `jsconfig.json`.

For your case, I've recreated your project in VS Code and it's working good "out-of-the-box" in getting type of `OtherTest` type [image]:

[VS Code Intelisence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZwif.png)

**EDIT:** But i think, the problem is not in VS Code, and you want to know which type of variable will come to function in general.

In this case, you can check out these options:

1. Use a statically typed language, e.g. TypeScript
2. Use a static type checker for Javascript, e.g. Flow
3. Use JSDoc

Comment: Oh yeah, in the index.js file I get intellisense from both the imported files, but I wish to have intellisense from the argument passed into the OtherTest.js file: for instance, I should be able to see the someFunc() method from the arg argument in OtherTest.js.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the answer, don't get the problem from the first look

Comment: JSDoc! That's the least invasive and most elegant solution. It's working now, just need to reference the type at the top and use it in the JSDoc. Works flawlessly! Thanks!